# How to make android jar library with inner xml (layout/string)

Tags: android, jar

I am creating a library, which should be distributed as a jar file.

Public function is `void SomeLibClass.showSomeDialog(Context context)` and task library is dialog show with a complex View inside. No activity, nothing difficult.

The pattern using library - developer add it to your project, and call in one place `SomeLibClass.showSomeDialog` and enjoy the funny dialog.

Seems logical that the resources needed to render the dialog were inside the jar file(to avoid errors such as: jar updated, but no resources) - we need in jar file: layout, string, drawable, etc.

And i want call resource by Id, like when i make layout i continue write like android:text="@string/hello"

But this logical thing to do can not be obtained.. now i make all resources in jar file with prefix, but how to solve the problem with the same id in R.java?

Or am I wrong look, and this is all we have to somehow do differently? Wants to repeat a simple - all you need for the library was in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to distribute Android-compatible Java code with resources, you need to use [an Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).

The upcoming r14 edition of the Android Developer Tools reportedly has the ability to package up a library project, including resources, as a JAR. r14 should be released soon -- I would wait until this is released and then see how to apply it to your project.

Comment: I installed the 14 version. Can you tell me how to use resources from jar file? :)

Comment: @Mihael Isaev: The r14 tools have not yet shipped, so I have not used them. I would wait until the r14 tools have been *released*, and then see how to apply this technique to your project. That being said, what little information we have about the feature can be found on http://tools.android.com/ and in the adt-dev Google Group.

Comment: Can you help me with resoources from jar?